# Python Implement makemigrations and migrate with c++/c?

Tags: python, django, cython, django-migrations, cpython

Latest project I am working on has 3500+ database models(grown rapidly form 620) which need to run makemigrations and migrate (which takes almost 6hours to complete on a skylake xeon single core).

I would like to implement the migration part is C++/C which I guess, can be faster.

How can I start experimenting with C/C++ with Python? Any simple code or guide? thanks,

Comment: How do you know the bottleneck is Python code? Have you profiled? Where is your code and results of profiling? What code have you identified to be the bottleneck that would benefit from being ported to C/C++ and what have you tried? Before going down blind alleys, do some research first. The bottleneck is almost definitely the DB and the schemas being used.

Comment: @danny the bottle neck is series execution of migrations, as python just uses only the single core. db is fast as it runs on same server with 30+ cores of CPU and 60+ GBs of ram. Execution of python while serving is through uwsgi and nginx which utilise all cpus while migration is bottlenecked

Comment: You could try using `import pyximport; pyximport.install(pyimport=True)` to compile everything possible in Cython as it is imported. For CPU limited generic Python code a speedup of around 30% might be realistic (although if you don't get that speedup there isn't much you can do to improve it). Anything more targeted is likely to be _a lot_ of work and require detailed profiling to identify slow bits, etc.

Comment: There's only one way to confirm where the bottleneck lies - profiling. Sequentially running migrations in SQL is going to be slow regardless of how the SQL is executed. If said migrations need to run sequentially because they are inter-dependent, what options are there? Again, profile the code to find out.